# Symfony2 subdomain firewall ignored on production server

Tags: security, symfony, subdomain, firewall

I got a very strange issue after deploying a new site.

The site uses a shop.domain.tld which is after a login. In the <kbd>security.yml</kbd> I defined a host parameter in my firewall and in the `access_control list`.

Locally (Vagrant) it works great, but online the firewall seems to be ignored.

```
firewalls:
    admin_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/admin
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: admin_login
            check_path: admin_authenticate
            provider: entity_admin
        logout:
            path: admin_logout
            target: /admin

    shop_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        host: .%domain%
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: homa_shop_login
            check_path: shop_authenticate
            provider: entity_user
        logout:
            path: shop_logout
            target: /

    validate:
        pattern: ^/validate
        security: false


access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/_wdt, roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/nl/contact, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/cart/quantity, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/validate, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/register/newcontact, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/forgot/password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: .%domain%, path:^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

`%domain%` is set in <kbd>parameters.yml</kbd> as domain.tld

The routes on the subdomain are working like expected, only the firewall is ignored.

Any idea?

Comment: How is `%domain%` defined? (it's just to check that there is no error with the declaration)

Answer (score 0):

> The site uses a shop.domain.tld
>
> `%domain%` is set in <kbd>parameters.yml</kbd> as domain.tld

Shouldn't you define `%domain%` as `"shop.domain.tld"`?

Or you should try to remove the `.` (dot) before `%domain%`, because according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014117/2257664) and the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html) the dot is not necessary.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But don't change anything I'm afraid.